# Building Turtlebot for Raspberry Pi 2 [Indigo] Two Questions

Tags: turtlebot, raspberrypi

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. What is the best way to build Turtlebot from source?
   Following the instructions in [ROSberryPiInstalling ROS Indigo on Raspberry Pi](http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Indigo%20on%20Raspberry%20Pi), I was able to install Indigo successfully. However, the turtlebot node was not included in the basic build. [This tutorial on Turtlebot installation](http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot/Tutorials/indigo/Turtlebot%20Installation) has instructions on how to build from source. It recommends installing `rocon, kobuki, turtlebot` from source as follows (similarly for the other two):

   $ `mkdir ~/rocon`

   $ `cd ~/rocon`

   $ `wstool init -j5 src https://raw.github.com/robotics-in-concert/rocon/indigo/rocon.rosinstall`

   $ `source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash`

   $  `rosdep install --from-paths src -i -y`

   $ `catkin_make`

   I chose not to go this route. Instead, I followed the instructions to install packages as described in Section 3 "Maintaining a Source Checkout" in the [earlier ROS/Raspberry Pi tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Indigo%20on%20Raspberry%20Pi).

   $ `cd ~/ros_catkin_ws`

   $ `rosinstall_generator rocom kobuki turtlebot --rosdistro indigo --deps --wet-only --exclude roslisp --tar > indigo-custom_ros.rosinstall`
   Next, update the workspace with wstool:

   $ `wstool merge -t src indigo-custom_ros.rosinstall`

   $ `wstool update -t src`
   After updating the workspace, you may want to run rosdep to install any new dependencies that are required:

   $ `rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro indigo -y -r --os=debian:wheezy`
   Finally, now that the workspace is up to date and dependencies are satisfied, rebuild the workspace:

   $ `sudo ./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release --install-space /opt/ros/indigo`

   So did I do the right thing by doing it this way?

   The instructions in the turtlebot installation are probably for developers who want to build from source, but not for someone who *has* to build from source because it is for a different processor (ARM7 in my case).

   But I am apprehensive because now I have to build **321** packages from source! Which brings me to question 2.
2. `libfreenect` and `libusb-1.0` linker issues. The first problem was a build failure when building `libreenect.so`. It complained about `libusb_get_parent` being an undefined symbol. Luckily someone had run into this before and [provided a solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28835794/undefined-reference-to-libusb-get-parent-compiling-freenect/30800980#30800980). The problem was that the Rasbian release has an older `libusb-1.0` and needs to be upgraded to version 1.0.18. That fixed the `libfreenect.so` build problem.

   However, a little further down the line when `freenect_camera` tried to link to `libfreenect.so`, the linker complained that `libusb_get_parent` is an undefined symbol. At this point I am stumped -- I've tried editing `package.xml` for `freenect_camera` (adding dependencies to `libusb`) and messing with `CMakeLists.txt` but nothing has worked.

   How do I get `freenect_camera` to link using the rebuilt `libusb-1.0`?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/211201/building-turtlebot-for-raspberry-pi-2-%5Bindigo%5D-two-questions/) by [sakumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/22747/sakumar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2015-06-12

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kosai](https://answers.ros.org/users/23512/kosai/) on 2015-08-10**:
Did you figure out the answer to your 2nd question? Have the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

sorry, I only just saw your question -- no, I was not able to resolve this issue. I felt I was too much on the bleeding edge to get things to work using Rasperry Pi (being new to ROS as well), so I switched to using an Intel NUC.

---

Originally posted by [sakumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/22747/sakumar/) with karma: 26 on 2015-08-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0